# Search and validate a year (four continuous digits) in text

Tags: regex

How do I validate that a string has only **4** contiguous digits or no digits?

I know that `/\d{4}/` will validate **4** contiguous digits, but if my string is dh25ah1233dadh3, it must be invalid.

Valid strings

```
dkskdsokd
adad dadad
addad1257adada
1587dadad
sasasas7854
```

Invalid strings

```
dh25ah1233dadh3
fsdfdfd1982fdf2
1some1422dd
```

Comment: Explain 'good text'/'bad text'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question, it'd be something like:

```
/^(?:\D*\d{4}\D*)*$/
```

That matches any number of the sub-pattern "some non-digits, then 4 digits, then some more non-digits".

If you want only one group of 4 digits, it'd be

```
/^\D*(?:\d{4})?\D*$/
```

*edit* — if you want the first one, and you don't want groups of 8 (or 12 or 16 ...) digits to be accepted, you'd do something like this:

```
/^(?:\D*\d{4}\D+)*$/
```

*edit* let's try this again:

```
/^(?:\D*\d{4}\D+)*(?:\D*\d{4})?$/
```

That allows the string to end with a 4-digit group.

Comment: Your first example would accept `12345678something`. I don't think that is intended either.

Comment: @Pointy I am really sorry to complain once more, but now you require the string to end with a non-digit character.

Comment: @m.buettner ha ha you're right :-)  No worries; I'll get it right eventually

Comment: Thanks!! 1111a2222 is invalid, only a group of four digits for text